# assigning print function to variable

Tags: python

For the following code, it seems to me that we are assigning the print function to the variable, spam.

```
spam = print('Hello!')
```

I'm wondering why doesn't calling spam, print out "Hello!"?

Comment: No, you are assigning the return of the print function to spam.

Comment: Because the line of code doesn't compile

Comment: @AK47 Yes it does.

Comment: @Alexander not in Python 2.7 - it throws a SyntaxError - Update: it compiles in Python 3

Comment: @JohnAnderson correct me if i'm wrong, but does this mean that the return of the print function != the actual printing of "Hello!" as an output?

Comment: @AK47 It's been almost 10 years. It's about time our discourse shifts its default assumption of version to be 3, not 2.

Comment: @etjk no, the return value of `print` is always `None`

Comment: thank you @Alexander, indeed I'm learning with Python 3.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see. So what is the output of "Hello!" actually referred as, if not "return value"?

Comment: @etjk The content that a function print to STDOUT or STDERR has absolutely nothing to do with the function's return value. It's a really common misconception that comes about from teachers teaching about `print`, instead of teaching newbies to be comfortable with playing with their code in a debugger

Comment: It is a *side-effect* of the `print` function. Just like `somelist.append(x)` has a side effect of mutating the list object, the print functions puts some bytes in the standard output buffer. Note, `.append` *also* returns `None`. Most functions that are used for a side effect return `None` in Python. One counter example would be `somelist.pop()` which mutes the list (a side effect) *and it also* returns the popped value

Answer (score 8):

Because `spam` isn't a function, it's the result of calling the function `print` with the argument `'Hello!'`, which is `None`, of type `NoneType`.

If you want to assign that expression to a variable, then you can use a lambda:

```
l = lambda: print('Hello!') # Doesn't actually call print
l() # 1. Prints 'Hello!'
l() # 2. Prints 'Hello!'
l() # 3. Prints 'Hello!'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spam = print('Hello!')
```

evaluates the expression on the right hand side and binds its value to `spam`. The return value of the (Python 3) `print()` function is `None`, so `spam` refers to `None`:

```
>>> spam = print('Hello!')
Hello!
>>> spam is None
True
```

One way to handle this is to create a partial function with `functools.partial()`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> spam = partial(print, 'Hello!')
>>> spam
functools.partial(<built-in function print>, 'Hello!')
>>> spam()
Hello!
```

Or a `lambda` expression:

```
>>> spam = lambda : print('Hello!')
>>> spam
<function <lambda> at 0x7f619cabf9d8>
>>> spam()
Hello!
```

Essentially both of the above use a closure around a function like this:

```
def printer(s):
    def f():
        print(s)
    return f

>>> spam = printer('Hello!')
>>> spam
<function printer.<locals>.f at 0x7f619cabfb70>
>>> spam()
Hello!
```

Comment: `>>> spam = print('Hello!')
Hello!`

For this, what is hello referred as? You mentioned that it is not the return value.

Thank you!

Comment: @etjk: the `Hello!` is there because that's what `print()` does - it prints a string to the terminal. That's why you see `Hello!` displayed, however, the actual _return_ value of the `print()` function is `None` as shown by `spam is None`.

Answer (score 0):

A function, depending on how that function is written, may or may not have an explicit return value.  It's up to the author of the function to decide how he wants to implement his function. A function with an explicit return value must have a `return` statement in it. The `return` statement causes the function to end and for the value following the `return` statement to be "returned" to the calling code.  When a function reaches the end of its code without an actual `return` statement, it's like there's an implicit `return None` at the end. So...

```
def is_5(num):
    if num is 5:
        return True
```

What happens above? If num is 5, the function returns the boolean value of True. But if num is not 5, there is no final `return` statement, so the implicit `None` is returned.

As to your question, there is also a difference between the "name" of a function and invoking the function. In our example above, the "name" of the function is `is_5`, and we invoke it by following the name of the function with parentheses.  If there are no parentheses following the function name, then the function name is just like any other variable, only it happens to hold a reference to a function. When you follow it with parentheses, that causes the function to be invoked. This is why we can call

```
is_5(2+3)
```

but we can also say:

```
myfunc = is_5
myfunc(2+3)
```

and get the same exact result.  As for `lambda` and `functools.partial`, both are used to create what are known as "nameless" functions -- they return a reference to a function, but that function has no name. You can capture the return from either of those and store it in a variable. Then, you can invoke the function by following the name of the variable with parentheses, just like above. Keep in mind that the function does not get run till it's invoked using parentheses.  So, for example:

```
mylambda = lambda x: True if x is 5 else None
mylambda(1+4)
```

Having said all this, regarding your question, the variable `spam` gets whatever the return value, if any, of the `print()` function returns. `print()` has no return value, so `spam` gets assigned the value `None`.  If you wanted to assign a reference to the print function to `spam`, you could say:

```
spam = print
```

And then later you could say

```
spam("Hello!")
```

and you would get your "Hello!" string printed to the screen at that time.

Also, having a return value and printing strings to the screen or terminal are two different things. A function could do both or neither of those things and still be a useful function. It all depends on what the coder was trying to accomplish.