# Unexpected output for lambda python 3

Tags: python, lambda, stdout

I am trying to use lambda for a usecase, but it seems not working. The following is what I tried

The below is what I used, in stackflow I came across many people getting output for this, but for me its None

```
from __future__ import print_function
f = lambda x: print(x)
f()
f("Hello") ### now out put is shown expected is Hello output
f("Hello") is None ## I checked if its None and it is
>>> True
```

[image]
then I tried something else

```
l = lambda x : sys.stdout.write(x)
l('hello') # this time its showing output as 5 instead of printing hello
>>> 5
```

[image]

I even tried something which is not using lambda, unfourtunately that too not working, and got None

```
from functools import partial
spam = partial(print, 'Hello!')
spam()
spam() is None
>>> True
```

I got this from the last answer in this question [assigning print function to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851402/assigning-print-function-to-variable)

Can anyone help me what I am missing and why I am not able to print the string?

Comment: This is really amazing!

Comment: With Python3 l('hello') is outputting hello and returning 5 on my system. With python2 I only get the hello output without the integer return value.

Comment: Please consider telling a bit more about the environment you are using. Also, if you just write a simple `print("Hello")`, does it appear correctly?

Comment: @tevemadar Yes print("Hello") prints Hello. I am using inside jupyter notebook

Comment: Are you perhaps supressing error messages somehow? If I put the first snippet into a single cell, the empty `f()` call raises `TypeError` for me both locally and on jupyter.org/try. Then the rest of the lines does not run, but the error message is pretty visible by default. Have you tried restarting the kernel? Based on your screenshot, you are at the 59-60th input, and who knows happened earlier.

Comment: @tevemadar I am also getting that error.. Its just that I want to try that, thats why put it there. I added the image to clarify

Comment: How about restarting the kernel?

Comment: @tevemadar will give a try now

Comment: from Mark Lutz book , if you want to print from the body of the lambda function, simply print(x)  in python 3.x where this becomes  a call expression instead of a statement, or say `sys.stdout.write(str(x)+'\n')` in either Python 2.x or 3.x to make sure its an expression portably.

Comment: @pygo still the count is also getting printed

Comment: What happened after restart? Say, "Kernel" menu, "Restart & Clear Output", and re-run a cell with
`from __future__ import print_function` and
`f = lambda x: print(x)` and `f("Hello")`. Though it may be worth mentioning that `from __future__ import print_function` is for Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

What's not expected? that `f('Hello') is None` evaluate to `True`? Well that's expected because it is `None`.

`lambda x: print(x)` has no 'return', only a side effect, and the side effect is to print stuff to the output. This is similar to a function

```
def func(x): 
    print(x)
```

which has no return statement, hence, if you evaluate the function, it's output will be `None`.

Comment: @ Rocky Li,  this is about when you call `l = lambda x : sys.stdout.write(x)` and then call it like `l('hello')` it returns `hello5` rather just `hello` !

Comment: Its not printing output. Say if I type f("Hello") it prints nothing. And in other case l('hello') prints the number of count of characters not string

Comment: @pygo: `l('hello')` prints `hello` (if flushed) and returns `5`, since `sys.stdout.write` returns the number of characters written, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write

Comment: @pygo How you getting the hello5 ? I am just getting 5

Comment: I am not sure why there is a different behaviour

Comment: @James,  output  i'm getting is `hello5`, try exit your python interpreter and jump into it again and then try the same `l = lambda x : sys.stdout.write(x); sys.stdout.flush()`  and `l("hello")`

Comment: @pygo Interesting I am just getting 5 .

Comment: I added an image

Comment: Try somthing like `l = lambda x: sys.stdout.write(str(x) + "\n")` and see the `l("hello")` not you will get hello and 6 into another line :-)

Comment: hmm, i would say if you could check this on the Linux box with python3.x or any other interpreter to see teh diff

Comment: @pygo Did you run this in notebook ?

Comment: @James, i never used notebook :-) .. i'm into linux python shell

Comment: @pygo haha this is funky. Now I am getting something like you , with the hello5. When tried in shell

Answer (score 2):

```
l = lambda x : sys.stdout.write(x)
l('hello') # this time its showing output as 5 instead of printing hello
>>> 5
```

it's probably because the write is not flushed, you can force this by manually calling

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

As for why it's returns `hello5` is because the Python shell prints out the return value of the previous statement, `sys.stdout.write()` returns the count of the written characters which in case of 'hello' is 5. thus they become concatenated into `hello5`. If you ran this in a normal Python file i.e `python filename.py` it would never print the `5` and only `hello`.

Comment: But how to print just "Hello" instead of the number of characters ?

Comment: Your code should work perfectly fine outside of the Python interpreter REPL (put it in a separate file and try)

Comment: @UkuLoskit I put this inside a python file and still it returning the number.l = lambda x : sys.stdout.write(x); sys.stdout.flush(). l(hello).. returned 5

Comment: @UkuLoskit,  sounds interesting though ,  you are right  outside interpreter  while keeping into a file then works as expected and do not return a number!

Comment: @gboffi, thanks, I just realized this as well, my mistake :)